# How does the [L] flag cause my url to partially duplicate?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set up a simple .htaccess file to direct requests to a sample index.php file as below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1   # [L] here changes output

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1
```

Accessing `devserver.com/foo/baz` results in a `$_GET['request']` of `bar/baz/baz`. Adding the `[L]` flag to the first `RewriteRule` gives my expected result, of `bar/baz`.

I have read many question/answers of people misunderstanding the [L] flag, thinking it will end all rewriting. I know that's not the case and don't see how the [L] flag should really make a difference here at all.

Here are the steps I envision happening here, first without [L]:

1. Request url starts as `foo/baz`
2. Request matches first rule, is rewritten to `bar/baz`
3. Request continues processing and matches the `RewriteCond`
4. Request matches next rule as well, rewritten to `index.php?request=bar/baz`
5. New iteration begins with request of `index.php?request=bar/baz`
6. New request matches no rules and is the final output

And with [L]:

1. Request url starts as `foo/baz`
2. Request matches first rule, is rewritten to `bar/baz`
3. New iteration begins with request of `bar/baz`
4. Request doesn't match until the `RewriteCond`
5. Request matches next rule, is rewritten to `index.php?request=bar/baz`
6. New iteration begins with request of `index.php?request=bar/baz`
7. New request matches no rules and is the final output

In this simplified scenario, I cannot fathom how `baz` gets duplicated. What am I misunderstanding?

EDIT: Adding this below the first RewriteRule results in a final `$_GET['request']` of `test/baz`. Not sure what this means:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/baz$
RewriteRule ^bar/baz/baz$ /test
```

Comment: So we all know `[L]` stops further rules from processing. The problem may be arising since your first redirection is a relative URL. Have you done any other tests with this?

Comment: I agree with **Rob W**, this is likely happening as a result of the redirection and therefore reprocessing of `/bar/baz`

Comment: @RobW, I've been trying tests around this for half the day, none of which have really shone any more of a light onto what's really going on. This is the bare-bones version. I'll edit one into the question though. I'm not sure how a relative URL would change things, since /bar* still shouldn't match anything.

Comment: Enable the RewriteLog - that should help in figuring out what _actually_ happens.

Comment: @CBroe, good thinking, I'll see what that uncovers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In contrast, the PATH_INFO that is appended to the URI before each
>   rule reflects only the value of PATH_INFO before this round of
>   mod_rewrite processing. As a consequence, if large portions of the URI
>   are matched and copied into a substitution in multiple RewriteRule
>   directives, without regard for which parts of the URI came from the
>   current PATH_INFO, the final URI may have multiple copies of PATH_INFO
>   appended to it.

In order to prevent that from happening, you need to use the DPI flag so your rule would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1
```

The DPI flag will take care of removing the path info from it. **[You can read more here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi)**

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the PATH_INFO functionality at all. This seems like it should be a more common problem if all it takes is a double-slashed URL....

Comment: @rotanimod yeah I wasn't either, I got very intrigued by what was causing the issue so I went to see the rewrite logs and notice the path info kicking in. Note that on httpd version prior to 2.11 or something like that there was also a bug on the postfix or something don't recall it.